# Instantiating with a Pool<T> class via PoolObjectFactory interface

Tags: java, android

Here is an example of using Java Pool (pool of generics) in order to instantiate TouchEvents for Android:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Pool<T> {
    public interface PoolObjectFactory<T> {
        public T createObject();
    }

    private final List<T> freeObjects;
    private final PoolObjectFactory<T> factory;
    private final int maxSize;

    public Pool(PoolObjectFactory<T> factory, int maxSize) {
        this.factory = factory;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.freeObjects = new ArrayList<T>(maxSize);
    }

    public T newObject() {
        T object = null;

        if (freeObjects.isEmpty()) {
            object = factory.createObject();
        } else {
            object = freeObjects.remove(freeObjects.size() - 1);
        }

        return object;
    }

    public void free(T object) {
        if (freeObjects.size() < maxSize) {
            freeObjects.add(object);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I don't really understand how this code works:

```
if (freeObjects.isEmpty()) {
    object = factory.createObject();
} else {
    object = freeObjects.remove(freeObjects.size() - 1);
}
```

Lets say we have:

```
touchEventPool = new Pool<TouchEvent>(factory, 100);
```

Does this mean it is going to store an Array of 100 events (and when #101 comes inside, will dispose #1, like first-in-first-out)?

I assume it supposed to hold some maximum number of objects and then dispose the extra. I read book's description like 10 times.. and couldn't get it. Maybe someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume it supposed to hold some maximum number of objects and then dispose the extra. I read book's description like 10 times.. and couldn't get it. Maybe someone explain how this works?

Sort of. The class keeps a cache of pre-created objects in a `List` called `pool`. When you ask for a new object (via the `newObject` method) it will first check the `pool` to see if an object is available for use. If the pool is empty, it just creates an object and returns it to you. If there is an object available, it removes the last element in the `pool` and returns it to you.

Annotated:

```
if (freeObjects.isEmpty()) {
    // The pool is empty, create a new object.
    object = factory.createObject();
} else {
    // The pool is non-empty, retrieve an object from the pool and return it.
    object = freeObjects.remove(freeObjects.size() - 1);
}
```

And when you return an object to the cache (via the `free()` method), it will only be placed back into the pool if the maximum size of the pool has not been met.

Annotated:

```
public void free(T object) {
    // If the pool is not already at its maximum size.
    if (freeObjects.size() < maxSize) {
        // Then put the object into the pool.
        freeObjects.add(object);
    }
    // Otherwise, just ignore this call and let the object go out of scope.
}
```

If the pool's max size has already been reached, the object you are freeing is not stored and is (presumably) subject to garbage collection.

Comment: @h3d0 Any time! I'm glad it helped you!

Comment: I was confused because of object = freeObjects.remove().. I thought that right part should be executed first, but that would doesn't make any sense since object will be equal null.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of any pool is in creating controlled environment where (usually) no need to create new (event) instances when some unused free instances can be re-used from the pool.

When you create 
`touchEventPool = new Pool<TouchEvent>(factory, 100);`
you hope 100 instances will be enough in any particular moment of the program live.

So when you want to get 101'st event the process probably will free first 5, 20 or even 99 events and the pool will be able to reuse any of them.

If there will be no free instances then depending on the pool policy the new one will be created or the requestor thread will wait other threads to release one and return to the pool. In this particular implementation the new one will be created.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main concept of object pool is to reduce frequency of object instanciations.

> Does this mean it is going to store an Array of 100 events (and when #101 comes inside, will dispose #1, like first-in-first-out)?Does this mean it is going to store an Array of 100 events (and when #101 comes inside, will dispose #1, like first-in-first-out)?

I don't think so. The maximum number 100 means that of freeObjects but of currently using objects. When an object is not used any more, you shall free it. Then the freed object won't be descarded but be stocked as a freeObject (the max num means that of these spared objects). Next time you need another new object, you don't have to instanciate a new object. All you need is just reusing one of spared freeObjects.

Thus you can avoid **costly** object instanciations. It can improve in performance.